# Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)

Tags: ubuntu, usb, nfc, smartcard-reader, acr122

I want to use my ACR122U contact-less smart card reader in Ubuntu 14 smarty. So I installed my required packages and drivers.

Finally when I want to use the reader I receive the following error:

```
rc@rc-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/itsme$ sudo nfc-list
[sudo] password for rc: 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.0
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:001:020
rc@rc-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/itsme$ 
rc@rc-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/itsme$ sudo mfoc -O output.txt
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)
No NFC device found.
rc@rc-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/itsme$
```

It seems that my reader is in use with a kernel tool. I searched a lot. there are a lot of people that had the same issue already, but I couldn't find my answer among them.

Does anybody has any idea how I can resolve this problem? (By reclaiming the device, for example)

Comment: If there is a PC/SC daemon running on your system, it will access the reader. So you might want to try to stop that daemon process.

Comment: Hi Hamid, if my answer below was correct, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo modprobe -r pn533_usb

sudo modprobe -r pn533
```

Works for me.

```
--------@--------:~$ sudo nfc-list
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
1 ISO14443A passive target(s) found:
ISO/IEC 14443A (106 kbps) target:
ATQA (SENS_RES): 00  04  
UID (NFCID1): ab  c9  67  00  
SAK (SEL_RES): 08
```

Comment: Worked on `Linux kali 5.5.0-kali2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.5.17-1kali1 (2020-04-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux` ! (latest live at the time of comment)

Answer (score 9):

If you have kernel version > 3.5, `nfs-list` and `pcscd` will report this error due to the automatic load of `pn533` driver.

To read the `pcscd` dameon output you can run it using: `pcscd -f -d`

1. Check which kernel version is installed: `uname -a`
2. Blacklist `pn533` and `nfc` drivers (references: [Arch Linux wiki Touchatag RFID Reader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchatag_RFID_Reader), [nfc-tools forum](http://forums.nfc-tools.org/post/5308/#p5308)):

   ```
   $ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf
   ```

   Add the following lines:

   ```
   blacklist pn533
   blacklist nfc
   ```
3. Disable kernel modules:

   ```
   $ modprobe -r pn533 nfc
   ```
4. Restart the `pcscd` daemon: `sudo service pcscd restart`

[Here you can fine a small program to test your ACR122U reader and a more detailed guide](https://github.com/goodotcom/rfid-reader-http).

Comment: As mentioned here in the following article, you may need to also disable pn533_usb.
Also, you can use modprobe -rf to force unloading. Be aware of the order, though. It will still fail if you try to unload a module with dependencies first.
https://medium.com/@andv/how-to-fix-acr122s-and-libnfcs-unable-to-claim-usb-interface-on-kali-linux-932a34bb8e32

Answer (score 4):

A quick-and-dirty solution:

```
sudo rmmod pn533 ## unload the driver right now
sudo nfc-list ## now it works...
```

Answer (score 0):

On newer ubuntu(>1804), blacklist pn533_usb is also needed

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf
blacklist nfc
blacklist pn533
blacklist pn533_usb
```