# Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy) Stuck

Tags: usb, ubuntu-16.04, nfc, smartcard-reader, acr122

I am trying to use the ACR122U reader. I installed everything, however when I use `nfc-list` or any other command I get :

```
me@me:~$ nfc-list 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:003:004
```

I searched and find several posts about the same problem such as:

[Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131569/unable-to-claim-usb-interface-device-or-resource-busy)

but their solution does not work for me. I have blacklisted `pn533` and `nfc` in

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf
```

however when I try to disable the kernel modules I get:

```
me@me:~$  modprobe -r pn533 nfc
modprobe: FATAL: Module pn533 is in use.
me@me:~$ modprobe -rf pn533 nfc
modprobe: FATAL: Module pn533 is in use.
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to claim USB interface (Device or resource busy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131569/unable-to-claim-usb-interface-device-or-resource-busy)

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to solve this issue by adding `blacklist pn533_usb` to:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf
```

so its content is:

```
blacklist nfc
blacklist pn533
blacklist pn533_usb
```

then run  `sudo modprobe -rf pn533_usb`